# Localhost not working in production in Docker

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, docker

I successfully ran MERN app in my local machine using docker. Then, just for fun, I wanted it to deply to AWS, EC2 instance. After deploying, the fetch call in react-app gives this error:

```
GET http://localhost:5000/posts/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
App.js:37 TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

I am just creating and getting posts from react app which gets saved in mongodb. This works well in the local machine but not in the Amazon EC2 instance(Ubuntu 18.04), it doesn't work even though the frontend part is still showing but gives error when there is a api call.

I sshed the instance and tried curl command inside it, it gave the correct result. But using public url provided, i.e, from react app, gives above error.

Here are some details and hope you guys can help me.

React: App.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

const serverUrl = 'http://localhost:5000'

const postModel = {
    title: '',
    body: '',
}

function App() {

    const [posts, setPosts] = React.useState([])
    const [post, setPost] = React.useState({ ...postModel })

    React.useEffect(() => {


        //get all the posts
        fetch(`${serverUrl}`, {
            method: 'GET',
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res)
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))

        //get all the posts
        fetch(`${serverUrl}/posts/`, {
            method: 'GET',
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                setPosts([...res])
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }, [])


    const _postChange = (e) => {
        setPost({ ...post, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
    }

    const _addPost = () => {
        //add new post

        const requestJson = JSON.stringify(post)
        console.log(requestJson)
        fetch(`${serverUrl}/post/add/`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: requestJson
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res)
                setPosts([...posts, { title: res.post.title, body: res.post.body }]);
                setPost({ ...postModel })
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }

    console.log(post)

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h2>All Posts</h2>
            <div>
                <input placeholder="Post Title" value={post.title} onChange={_postChange} type="text" name="title" />
                <input placeholder="Post body" value={post.body} onChange={_postChange} name="body" />
                <button onClick={_addPost}>Add</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                {posts.map((instance, index) => {
                    return <div key={index}>
                        <h4>{instance.title}</h4>
                        <p>{instance.body}</p>
                        <hr />
                    </div>
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

React: Dockerfile

```sh
# build environment
FROM node:12.2.0-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent
COPY . /app
RUN npm run build

# production environment
FROM nginx:1.16.0-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

React: package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "cra-template": "1.0.3",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

backend: index.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const Post = require('./models/Post');
const cors = require('cors')

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());


// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose
  .connect(
    'mongodb://mongo:27017/node-mongo-docker',
    { useNewUrlParser: true }
  )
  .then(() => console.log('MongoDB is on'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));


//test the work
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.json({ 'message': 'Working properly' })
})

//get all posts
app.get('/posts', (req, res) => {
  console.log("Getting of posts")
  Post
    .find()
    .then(posts => res.json(posts))
    .catch(err => res.json({ 'error': err }))
})

//post a new post
app.post('/post/add', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body)
  const newPost = new Post({
    title: req.body.title,
    body: req.body.body,
  })
  newPost
    .save()
    .then(post => res.json({ 'post': post }))
});

const port = 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log('Server is on'));
```

backend: Dockerfile

```sh
FROM node:12.2.0-alpine 

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

backend: package.json

```
{
  "name": "node-mongo-docker",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "mongoose": "^5.2.7",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  react:
    container_name: react-app
    build: ./react-app
    ports: 
      - '80:80'
    links:
      - server
  server:
    container_name: node-mongo-docker
    restart: always
    build: ./node-mongo
    ports:
      - '5000:5000'
    links:
      - mongo
    # volumes:
    #   - '.:/usr/src/app'
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to replace "localhost" with the url of the deployed back-end.

React is a **client-side** javascript library, and runs in the users web browser, so it will use the "localhost" of the user that visits your page, **not** the server's localhost.